# JPA : entities with null property not retrieved

Tags: jpa, repository, jpql

I have two entities :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_CLIENT")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Client implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "nom")
    private String nom;

    @OneToOne
    private TypeClient typeClient;



@Entity
@Table(name = "T_TYPECLIENT")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class TypeClient implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nom")
    private String nom;
```

I want to do that query :

```
@Query("Select id, nom, code, codeComptable, typeClient from Client")
List<Object[]>  findAllWithoutForeignKey();
```

JPA returns only client with typeClient <> null.

How do I have to do to get all clients?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your query translates to `inner join` between `Client` and `TypeClient`. Try this

```
@Query("Select c.id, c.nom, c.code, c.codeComptable, tc from Client c left join c.typeClient tc")
```

Comment: It doesn't work, Tomcat can't start server with this query : Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.myapp.repository.ClientRepository.findAllWithoutForeignKey()!

Answer (score 0):

The relationship `Client` to TypeClient is not `OneToOne`, but rather `ManyToOne`. Try changing that, and it might work.